# How to check/uncheck a QTableView and trigger setData()

Tags: python, checkbox, pyqt, qtableview

I have a custom `QTableModel` which I'm displaying using `QTableView` in PyQt.  I have some fields set as checkable, and I want to add check all and check none buttons.  I feel there should be a way to cause the `setData()` to be called from the code in such a way that the checked state will change as well as the code I have already written in `setData()`.  Is there in fact a way to do this?

Here is the setData I'm using, as requested:

```
if role == Qt.CheckStateRole:
        row = index.row()
        column = index.column()

        if row == 0 and column != 0:
            self._data.parsingConfiguration['columnEnabled'][column-1] = True if value == Qt.Checked else False
            self.dataChanged.emit(self.createIndex(1, column), self.createIndex(len(self._data.data),column))

            if column-1 == self._data.parsingConfiguration['groupNumberColumn']:
                self.setGroupNumber(self.getFirstEnabledMember())
            elif column-1 == self._data.parsingConfiguration['timeStepColumn']:
                self.setTimeStep(self.getFirstEnabledMember())
            self.emit(SIGNAL("layoutChanged()"))
            return True
        if column == 0 and row != 0:
            self._data.parsingConfiguration['rowEnabled'][row-1] = True if value == Qt.Checked else False
            self.dataChanged.emit(self.createIndex(row, 1), self.createIndex(row, self._data.numColumns+1))
            return True
        return False
```

Comment: Just to clarify: you want two widgets outside your QTableView whose activation changing the 'checked' state of your model items, right ? Could you post you `setData` ?

Comment: I second @PierreGM. Show code. This is too vauge.

Comment: Code added, sorry I wasn't more clear.  Ultimately I want to know if there is a feasible way to call setData myself so I can keep code in a single place.

Answer (score 0):

After a little more trial and error I discovered that I can change the data which is informing the data function's return on QCheckState, then emit a layoutChanged() signal from the model.  This still does not call the setData method, and did require separate functions be written (thus not completing my initial goal), however it does achieve the desired results from a user perspective.

Comment: Can you post your solution? I'm having the same issue (check all/clear all).